# objectdatasource question

Tags: c#, asp.net

For the moment, I'm binding my gridviews by calling a linq query that returns a list collection of objects MyObject. In my gridview, if I'm using a boundfield I set its Datafield property to the name of the property of MyObject and if I'm using an itemtemplate I work with Eval. In my code behind, I have

```
MyGridview.DataSource = MyListOfMyObject;
MyGridview.DataBind();
```

All seems to work fine.

What's the purpose of adding an ObjectDataSource control in the aspx file. What does it do extra?

Thanks.

PS: I'm new to the .net framework and I'm still figuring things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://asp.dotnetheaven.com/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/objectdatasource.aspx):

> ObjectDataSource belongs to the family
>   of data source controls in ASP.NET,
>   which enables a declarative
>   databinding model against a variety of
>   underlying data stores, such as SQL
>   databases or XML. Most data source
>   controls encourage a two-tiered
>   application architecture, where the
>   presentation layer (the page)
>   interacts directly with the backend
>   data provider.
>
> However, it is also
>   common for page developers to
>   encapsulate data retrieval (and
>   optionally business logic) into a
>   component object, introducing an
>   additional layer between the
>   presentation page and data provider.
>   The ObjectDataSource control allows
>   developers to structure their
>   applications using this traditional
>   three-tiered architecture and still
>   take advantage of the ease-of-use
>   benefits of the declarative
>   databinding model in ASP.NET.